# Cannot click inside text input

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a basic form with a few fields. However I cannot click on the item name input field upon hovering. I can focus on it by hitting tab but the click doesn't work. Is this a CSS alignment issue? What am I doing wrong? Please help!

This is a screenshot of the form field :

[image: The second input text area is the problematic one]

Here is the code snippet in the sand box :

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-frost-gp7pj?from-embed

Will the onFocus work for this problem?

Here is the code snippet :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";
import "react-dropdown/style.css";

import styled from "styled-components";

const InputText = styled.input.attrs({
  className: "form-control"
})``;

const RaiseMRNForm = styled.div.attrs({})`
  background-color: papayawhip;
  width: 100%;

  height: auto;
`;

const ModalWrapper = styled.div.attrs({})`
  border: 1px solid #d0cccc;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  transition: all 0.8s;
  height: 400%;
`;

const ModalHeader = styled.div.attrs({})`
  background-color: #035385;

  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
`;

const MRNHeading = styled.div.attrs({})`
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 1%;
`;

const CrossButton = styled.div.attrs({})`
  color: white;
  width: 5%;
  float: right;
`;

const InputTextAreas = styled.div.attrs({})`
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
`;

const InputClient = styled.div.attrs({})`
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
`;

const InputStockItem = styled.div.attrs({})`
  width: 40%;
  float: left;

  margin-top: 1%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
`;

const StockInformation = styled.div.attrs({})`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;

  margin-top: 7%;
`;

const DropDownContainer = styled.div.attrs({})`
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
`;

const InputStockQuantity = styled.div.attrs({})`
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
`;

const InputStockUnit = styled.div.attrs({})`
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
`;

const ModalFooter = styled.div.attrs({})`
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #035385;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
`;

const AddButton = styled.button.attrs({})`
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  height: 6%;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-out;
  &:hover {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    color: white;
  }
`;

const CancelButton = styled.button.attrs({})`
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  height: 5%;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-out;
  &:hover {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    color: white;
  }
`;

const options = ["Safety", "Consumable", "Machinery", "Hardware"];

class MRNmodal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: true,
      close: false,

      value: "Safety"
    };
  }

  handleChangeInputClientName = async event => {};

  handleChangeInputStockItemName = async event => {
    const itemName = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ itemName });

    console.log("Inside handleChangeInputStockItemName ========> ", itemName);
  };

  handleChangeInputStockItemQuantity = async event => {
    const itemQuantity = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ itemQuantity });

    console.log(
      "Inside handleChangeInputStockItemQuanity ========> ",
      itemQuantity
    );
  };

  handleChangeInputStockItemUnit = async event => {
    const itemUnit = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ itemUnit });

    console.log("Inside handleChangeInputStockItemUnit ========> ", itemUnit);
  };

  handleDropdownChange = option => {
    console.log("Inside handleDropdownChange ", option);
    this.setState({ itemType: option.label });
    console.log("this.state.itemType", this.state.itemType);
  };

  render() {
    var {
      clientName,
      itemName,
      itemQuantity,
      itemUnit,

      show,
      close
    } = this.state;

    show = true;
    close = false;

    return (
      <div>
        <ModalWrapper
          style={{
            transform: show ? "translateY(0vh)" : "translateY(-100vh)",
            opacity: show ? "1" : "0"
          }}
        >
          <ModalHeader>
            <MRNHeading>
              <h3>Raise MRN</h3>
            </MRNHeading>
            <CrossButton>
              <span>
                <h1>x</h1>
              </span>
            </CrossButton>
          </ModalHeader>

          <RaiseMRNForm>
            <InputTextAreas>
              <InputClient>
                <p style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Enter Client Name</p>

                <InputText
                  style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
                  type="text"
                  value={clientName}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeInputClientName}
                />
              </InputClient>

              <InputStockItem>
                <p style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Enter Stock Item Name</p>

                <InputText
                  style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
                  type="text"
                  value={itemName}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeInputStockItemName}
                />
              </InputStockItem>
            </InputTextAreas>

            <StockInformation>
              <DropDownContainer>
                <p style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Enter Stock Type</p>
                <Dropdown
                  value={this.state.itemType}
                  options={options}
                  onChange={this.handleDropdownChange.bind(this)}
                  placeholder="Select an option"
                />
              </DropDownContainer>

              <p style={{ textAlign: "left", marginLeft: "50%" }}>
                Enter Stock Quantity
              </p>
              <InputStockQuantity>
                <InputText
                  style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
                  type="text"
                  value={itemQuantity}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeInputStockItemQuantity}
                />
              </InputStockQuantity>

              <InputStockUnit>
                <p
                  style={{
                    textAlign: "left",
                    marginLeft: "0%",
                    marginTop: "30%"
                  }}
                >
                  Enter Stock Unit
                </p>
                <InputText
                  style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
                  type="text"
                  value={itemUnit}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeInputStockItemUnit}
                />
              </InputStockUnit>
            </StockInformation>


          </RaiseMRNForm>

          <ModalFooter>
            <CancelButton>CLOSE</CancelButton>
            <AddButton onClick={this.handleIncludeClient}>CONTINUE</AddButton>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MRNmodal;
```

I am including a major chunk of the code since I don't know if it's a CSS issue.

Comment: The input `id` must be the same as the label's `for` attribute. Edit: Just looked at the example, you're using `<p>` for the input labels. You must use `<label>`.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, works as expected.

Comment: We cannot find the issues from your url. can u plz share this in codepen or fiddle?

Comment: Please use this url : https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-frost-gp7pj?from-embed

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I added a significant part of the code because I was not sure if this was a CSS alignment issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HTML `<label>` element instead of an `<p>` will already solve the first issue. By doing that you will be able to select the input field.

By using the [htmlFor](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor) attribute on that label, and an ID on the corresponding input you will also be able to click on the label itself to target the input field.

The `htmlFor` is React's way of using the [HTML for attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp).

**Short example snippet:**

```js
<InputClient>
  <label
    htmlFor="inputClientName" // this targets the input
    style={{ textAlign: "left" }}
  >
    Enter Client Name
  </label>
  <InputText
    id="inputClientName" // consistent id (make it unique)
    style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
    type="text"
    value={clientName}
    onChange={this.handleChangeInputClientName}
  />
</InputClient>
```

**Working example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-tree-fb0fd

Comment: Hello Remi, thank you so much for your response. I really appreciate it. I made the changes you suggested and am able to see the cursor when I hover over the text box. However it is still not clickable. Any ideas?

Comment: @sublime_archon That is odd. Have you . tried the codesandbox I provided? (the link behind "working example:") Are you able to click on those input fields?

Comment: I would suggest removing the 'position absolute' definitions. And instead add `<div>`'s around each label and input pair. That makes a responsive easier to create. I'll add an example to the codesandbox.

Comment: Updated the codesandbox. The styling is probably off since the elements are now placed a bit random. But  that's the direction you want to start looking. Position absolute in combination with floating divs (= position relative) will not work.